# Determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix in terms of $n-1\times n-1$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose we know  the determinant of matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n-1}$. Can we express determinant of matrix $A'=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n}$ in terms of the determinant of matrix $A$?

We see that the matrix $A'$ differs from matrix $A$ only in the extra right-most column and bottom row. As a starting point, we can think of case $n=3$.

Comment: No. Take any $A$ with nonzero determinant and have last row of $A'$ be all $0$s.

Comment: Actually, yes. $\det(A') = 0\cdot \det(A)+\det(A')$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, e.g., consider:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
A = \left(\matrix{0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}\right) & \quad\quad & B = \left(\matrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 }\right) \\
A' = \left(\matrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1}\right) & \quad\quad & B' = \left(\matrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1}\right)
\end{array}$$

$A$ and $B$ have the same determinant (namely $0$) and $A'$ and $B'$ are obtained from them by adding the same third row and column, but $|A'| = -1 \neq 0 = |B'|$.

Comment: I am already given the fixed entries of matrices $A$ and $A'$. For example, the matrices $A$ and $A'$ you have provided. Can we split the determinant of $A'$ as a function of the determinant of $A$. Anyway, I was already convinced that the question is too much general.

Comment: No: think of my $B$ and $B'$ as what your $A$ and $A'$ might have been in an alternative universe. You can't give $|A'|$ as a function of $|A|$ and the entries in the extra row and column, because as $|A| = |B|$ that would give you the same answer for $|B'|$, but $|A'| \neq |B'|$.

Comment: Yes That is right!

Answer (score 4):

In general no. You need to know the values of the entries of the extra row and column. Note that if it were possible, one could iterate the process and express the determinant of any matrix in terms of the value of its corner entry (say first row, first column).

**Edit.** As Rob pointed out in the comments, you need to know the internals of $A$ too.

Comment: You need to know the internals of $A$ too. See my answer. I think the OP was hoping to be able to calculate the determinant as a function of the determinant of $A$ and of the values added in the last row and column in $A'$.

Comment: You are right about the internals of $A$ being needed too.

Answer (score 1):

No-ish, in that there exists a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) for computing the determinant perturbatively
$$\det\left(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{uv}^\textsf{T}\right) = \det\left(\mathbf{A}\right) + \mathbf{v}^\textsf{T}\mathrm{adj}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)\mathbf{u}$$
but the perturbing term $\mathbf{v}^\textsf{T}\mathrm{adj}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)\mathbf{u}$ is not solely a function of the determinant $\det\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

What connects the determinant of a matrix and its leading principal minor is [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). In general, if a leading principal submatrix $A$ of a partitioned matrix $M$ is nonsingular, we have
$$
\det\underbrace{\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}}_M=\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B),
$$
where $S=D-CA^{-1}B$ is called the Schur complement of $A$ in the partitioned matrix $M$.

Comment: Closely related